# iOS 8 Swift app appears magnified

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, user-interface, swift

Why do the UI objects in my app appear larger than in other apps?

The text is bigger and the status & navigation bars are even taller.

I've tried adjusting Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size, but that just affects every app the same way. So, at every setting, my app still looks magnified (or zoomed-in) compared to other apps.

Platform: iPhone 6 with iOS 8

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new project from one of Xcode's iOS templates.
2. Copy the `LaunchScreen.xib` file to your project.
3. Add the `LaunchScreen` line to your `Info.plist` file.